# Store list of forms in an array

Tags: c#, winforms, list

I have a program that needs to navigate through a series of screens in a given order.  What I’d like to do is to manage this centrally, using something analogous to a class factory, where I send a request for the next form, and it instantiates and returns the next form.  I have the following, however, this will instantiate all the forms immediately:

```
private List<Form> screens = new List<Form>() { new Form1(), new Form2(), … };
private Form currentForm;
private int currentPos;

public Form Next()
{            
    currentForm = screens[++currentPos];
    return currentForm;
}
```

Is there a way to defer instantiation until the actual request is made?  For example:

```
private List<Form> screens = new List<Form>() { Form1,Form2, …};
private Form currentFrm;
private int currentPos;

public Form Next()
{            
    currentForm = new screens[++currentPos];
    return currentFrm;
}
```

(this won't compile)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do that is to store types in your list and use [Activator.CreateInstance()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wccyzw83.aspx) to dynamically create the form instances:

```
private Type[] screenTypes = new Type[] {
    typeof(Form1),
    typeof(Form2),
    ...
};

private Form currentForm;
private int currentPos;

public Form Next()
{            
    currentForm = (Form) Activator.CreateInstance(screenTypes[++currentPos]);
    return currentForm;
}
```

Comment: afaik, if you're sure in the resulting type, you should use `cast`, not operator `as`

Comment: @abatishchev, well, that depends if you want to return `null` or throw an exception if one of the types does not derive from `Form`. In our case, your approach is probably best though, I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a list of delegates, eg:

```
List<Func<Form>> screens = new List<Func<Form>>
{
  () => new Form1(),
  () => new Form2(),
  ...
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private List<Type> screens = new List<Type>() { typeof(Form1), typeof(Form2), … };

Type t = screens[++currentPos];
return (Form)Activator.CreateInstance(t);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option...

```
public IEnumerable<Form> Forms
{
    yield return new Form1();
    yield return new Form2();
    yield return new Form3();
    ...    
}
```

Comment: `yield return` you probably mean :)